# How can the tablename used be dynamically determined in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wanting to have a VLOOKUP where the table I use is dynamically determined.... for instance:

```
If I have tables named Rnd_1, Rnd_2, Rnd_3...
```

I want to be able to pick which table the VLOOKUP will use based on the number...

`I have tried =VLOOKUP("value",CONCATENATE("Rnd_"+A1),2,FALSE) where A1 has a valid numeric value.`
This would not work.

`I also tried =VLOOKUP("value",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Rnd_"+A1)),2,FALSE)`
This also would not work.

How can the tablename to use be dynamically determined?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add an example mock spreadsheet to allow us to see what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. but actually, I must have had a syntax issue in my formula because the version with the INDIRECT works as I expected.

Comment: The issue in your original formula is the `"Rnd_"+A1` which should be `"Rnd_",A1`

Comment: If you want to use an operator for concatenation, Excel uses `&` and not `+`.  So `"Rnd_" & A1` would also produce your string.

Answer (score 1):

Both Engineer Toast and Byron Wall gave you the correct answer. The `concatenate()` function would be `concatenate("Rnd_", $A$1)` or you could simply make that argument `"Rnd_"&$A$1`

I would add one thing. If you leave `A1` as is, it will be handled as a relative reference. This means that when you copy and paste the formula, it will refer to the cell in the new position relative to where it was in the old position. In order to keep the formula point at `A1` you need to use a $, so `$A$1`. You could also name the cell where you want to pick up the value and do this `"Rnd_"&ValName`, that way the reference always points to that one cell... That is if you don't want it to be relative.

One last tip. If you have a very large datasets, you want to keep things as simple as possible, as this will keep overhead low. Make a concatenation cell next to your dynamic cell, say `B1` and make it `="Rnd_"&$A$1` and then have the `vlookup` argument point to `B1`, otherwise you may end up having excel call the concatenation function thousands of times when it doesn't need to, slowing down the execution of your calculations.